# xcode 7 : blue line on scroll bar

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

As yellow line indicate that your class has warnings. What blue line indicate appear on scroll bar find in xcode 7. while navigate to that line of code nothing found (or happened).

[image]

Comment: May be Memory leak indicate Blue line in Xcode.

Comment: may be but Like yellow line it is not display further information like we can see warning information on left side of class in yellow line  . so what is use of this indicator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see blue lines where I have breakpoints.

Comment: yes @rmaddy I just find out it and I am going to answer it myself :) . anyway thank you :)